# how to pick single row from multiple rows in pandas

Tags: sql, pandas

if I have two rows for the same ID, then I have to check for col2 and pick rows with values N and Q and skip the row with U. If there is single record with col2=U, then let it be. so for ID 123 and 555, output is with col2 N and Q resp.

```
ID    Col1    Col2     Col3
123   AAA     N        true
123   BBB     U        true
000   AAA     N        true
222   CCC     U        false
555   FIC     Q        false
555   VAN     U        true
```

expected output is:

```
Expected output:
ID    Col1    Col2     Col3
123   AAA     N        true
000   AAA     N        true
222   CCC     U        false
555   FIC     Q        false
```

how can I do this in pandas ?
in sql, I tried with having count(*)>1, and then picked these columns.

Comment: What if there are 2 rows for the same id with N and Q?

Comment: Just pick anyone if there are 2 rows with N and Q

Comment: If you want a solution with sql you should also tag with the database that you use.

Comment: @chits is any of the proposed answer working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach is to sort your dataframe by `Col2` ensuring that 'U' will end up last. There are several possibilities:

#### [pandas.Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)

This sets an ordered categorical type on Col2

```
categories = np.append(np.setdiff1d(df['Col2'], ['U']), ['U'])
df['Col2'] = pd.Categorical(df['Col2'], categories=categories, ordered=True)
df.sort_values(by='Col2').groupby('ID').first()
```

#### Split dataframe

This splits the dataframe in two based on the values of Col2 (not-U and U), and concatenates the two parts to ensure the U are at the end

```
pd.concat([df.query('Col2 != "U"'), df.query('Col2 == "U"')]).groupby('ID').first()
```

#### Custom sort order

This manually defines the sorting order from a list

```
custom_order = ['N', 'Q', 'Z', 'U']
custom_order_dict = dict(zip(custom_order, range(len(custom_order))))
df.sort_values(by='Col2', key=lambda x: x.map(custom_order_dict)).groupby('ID').first()
```

#### input

```
    ID Col1 Col2   Col3
0  123  AAA    N   True
1  123  BBB    U   True
2    0  AAA    N   True
3  222  CCC    U  False
4  555  FIC    Q  False
5  555  VAN    U   True
6  777  UUU    U  False
7  777  ZZZ    Z   True
8  999  UUU    U  False
9  999  NNN    N   True
```

#### output

```
    Col1 Col2   Col3
ID                  
000  AAA    N   True
123  AAA    N   True
222  CCC    U  False
555  FIC    Q  False
777  ZZZ    Z   True
999  NNN    N   True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
df.drop_duplicates('ID')
```

[image]

Above code keep always first record. You can change this with **last** instead of **first** record.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep="first")
df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep="last")
```

[image]

or you may sort for any column and then using of `drop_duplicates` method. In this way,  (by order Ascending or Descending) you may use `keep="first"` for **Min** or **Max**.

Comment: But how will it know that I have to drop col2=U ? I would like keep col2=N/Q.

Comment: @chits is N always before U?

Comment: No it’s random .

Comment: It’s not keep random. Above code keep always first record.

Comment: the value in col2 can be V or Z as well. so sorting might not work.

Comment: For this, you must add additional column for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a solution with multiple steps. this might not be the best way to do it but I did not find any other solution.

First step:
Separate records/rows for multiple ID's

```
df_multiple_record=pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("ID") if len(g) > 1)
Output:
ID    Col1    Col2     Col3
123   AAA     N        true
123   BBB     U        true
555   FIC     Q        false
555   VAN     U        true
```

Second Step:

drop the record with col2='U'

```
df_drop_U=df_multiple_record[df_multiple_record['Col2']!='U']
output:
ID    Col1    Col2     Col3
123   AAA     N        true
555   FIC     Q        false
```

third Step:

drop the duplicates on ID from main extract to get the records for single occurance of ID

```
df_single_record=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep=False)
output:
ID    Col1    Col2     Col3
000   AAA     N        true
222   CCC     U        false
```

fourth step:

concatenate single record df with the df where we drop U

```
df_final=pd.concat([df_single_record,df_drop_U],ignore_index=True)
output:
ID    Col1    Col2     Col3
000   AAA     N        true
222   CCC     U        false
123   AAA     N        true
555   FIC     Q        false
```